# BayesNet Independence

Tags: independence, bayesian-network, conditional-independence

For BayesNet, can anyone explain how we can check the independence between the set of random variables? e.g. $\{B, D\} \perp \{G, I\} | A?$

[image]

Comment: Yes, and so can any number of freely available resources. [stats.SE] is designed for well-researched questions. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I found that we can find a path and check whether there is an active trail or not. But when we have these multiple RVs I wonder if we need to find paths of four combinations of RVs?